# Website inside iframe in html. In a new way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have issue in one thing might never ask anybody in this community. Because I thing always bit different to other. I create a website I want it always open inside iframe of other website. 
**For example**
Let consider - `http://example.com` is main website and `http://abcd.co.za` is second website.

Is it possible suppose if user run `http://abcd.co.za` in address bar it would automatically redirect to `http://example.com` and then there inside iframe  `http://abcd.co.za` webpage will open?

**Why I do this**
I have low grade domain there I made a registration form if registration success then we sent email to user for email verification. If user click on that link of e-mail then he/she will redirect to that website.  Which I  don't like to tell about user that I have low grade domain. But at main website I have bit good domain but he not provide email system .

> **NO MATTER ABIUT DOMAIN ..** Please tell me how to create a iframe always open based on my question.

```
 <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://abcd.co.za" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: This is one of the craziest things I've ever heard of.  You're aware of all the side effects of what you're doing?  That crawlers aren't going to index your page correctly?  That you're slowing your site down?  That you're making a usability nightmare?  All because you have some wonky domain setup...

Comment: *«Because I think always bit different to others.»* --- Well, maybe that is your main issue. Try to stop re-invent the wheel and code like it it is efficient to code. You'll save time for yourself and the time of anyone trying to support you weird ideas. -- It's a vote to close on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Javascript to check whether the welcome page at  "https://abcd.co.za" (eg: index.html) has been opened inside an iframe. If not redirect to "http://example.com".

```
<script>
    if (window.top == window.self) {
        window.location = "http://example.com";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where I add this code.? Might u understand different. I want `abcd.co.za` always open inside iframe of `example.com` because `.com` is top level domain and `.co.za`http://abcd.co.za` ` is nt.

Comment: @Albert If you don't know what this code does, you should understand it before just copying and pasting.  Ask questions.

Comment: No i understand your code required to add on `abcd.co.za` page. But issue is in email verification link there is token. And token required to verify to that original domain or page. How I make this correct!

Comment: @Albert then you also want to pass query params... that's another issue. Email validation is made at example.com or at abcd.co.za?

Comment: Let support user email verification link is `abcd.co.za?Token=123456` I want if user click on that he will redirect to `example.com` iframe open `abcd.co.za?Token=123456` and verify token and process registration.

Comment: That help user not seen the original validate page of token and my bad domain also hidden to user.

Comment: How I do this.pls help.